# What is the easiest way to migrate Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova projects from Visual Studio 2013 to 2015

Tags: visual-studio-cordova

Visual Studio 2015 cannot open Visual Studio Tools for Apache Cordova projects created with Visual Studio 2013. Apart from the Project GUID change, there is a project layout change. Besides creating a blank project and copying everything over, is there an easier way?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to the documentation [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md#known-issues---visual-studio-2015), starting with "To migrate your previous projects to the new structure:" to migrate your 2013 project to a 2015 project. The document should cover the steps to do so.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

From [this article](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-docs/blob/master/known-issues/known-issues-vs2015.md#known-issues---visual-studio-2015) - To migrate your previous projects to the new structure:

1. Make a backup of your existing project (obligatory first step :))
2. Create a new project using the JavaScript \ Apache Cordova Apps \
   Blank App template

   - For TypeScript projects, you can use the TypeScript equivalent of this same project
3. Copy the .jsproj and taco.json files created by this template into your own project's folder
4. In your project, create a new folder named www
5. Delete the following folders from your project's folder:

   - bin
   - bld
6. Leave the following folders/files in your project directory:

   - merges
   - res
   - plugins
   - config.xml
7. Copy all other files/folders into the www folder
8. If you're using TypeScript, you'll need to add a tsconfig.json to your project folder and define config settings for your project. See the Configuring TypeScript section for details.
9. Now you can build and run your application

If you have errors, you may need to update file references to reflect the new folder structure.

Lastly, you should add the following XML elements to your config.xml to ensure your icons and splash screens are picked up by right clicking on the file and selecting "View Code":

```
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" height="62" />
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" height="173" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920"/>
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920"/>
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" height="800"/>
  </platform>
```